# how to write to common register from two always block

Tags: verilog, fpga, xilinx

In my application i need to access register from two always blocks.
first block will be of xillinx axi interface.
when user will write 1 via axi i need to start working in another always block and when its done  i want to clear that reg i.e make it 0.
Can you please suggest logic to achieve required functionality.
but issue is that i cant write to flag from two always blocks.
psudo code

```
//from axi interface always block

flag=1;
//axi interface block code end

//my custom always block
always @(posedge mainclk) //50Mhz main clokc
begin
if(flag==1)
begin
//so some task
flag=0;
end
end
```

Comment: Are they using a common clock or are the running on different clocks?

Comment: no, flag=1 is from axi interface it has its own clock

Comment: They are working on two different clocks.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use signals from different clock domains *as-is*.

In your case the 'flag' signal must be synchronized to the mainclk:

```
reg flag_meta,flag_sync;
always @(posedge mainclk or negedge reset_n)
begin
   if (!reset_n)
   begin
      flag_meta <= 1'b0;
      flag_sync <= 1'b0;
   end
   else
   begin
      flag_meta <= flag;
      flag_sync <= flag_meta;
   end
end
```

In a similar way your 'done' signal must synchronized to the AXI clock:

```
reg done_meta,done_sync;
always @(posedge aclk or negedge reset_n)
... // etc.
```

In your AXI code you need to clear the 'flag'. Something like:

```
always @(posedge aclk or negedge reset_n)
begin
   ... // some code that sets the 'flag' 
   ... // probably on an AXI write
      if (done_sync)
         fag <= 1'b0;
   end
end
```

There is a caveat:
This only works if both 'flag' and 'done' change slowly. There must be at least two clock cycles on each side to pass the change on. This is most important if you transfer a signal from a fast to a slow clock.